# Behavior of getSelection() API on CLICK event

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection

If I select whole text from this div then output will be 'abc1234'. when I click between 'c' and '1' output should be 'abc'. but it return previous highlighted text (in this case, 'abc1234'). if I click again at the same position then it returns the expected output (in this case, 'abc'). Is there any way I can get my expected output at the first click?

```js
$('.test-subject').on('click', function(){
 var sel = window.getSelection();
 console.log(sel.toString());
});

// start selecting the whole text
const range = new Range();
range.selectNode( $('.test-subject')[0] );
window.getSelection().addRange( range );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-subject">abc1234</div>
```

Comment: what is your expected output??

Comment: suppose, 'abc1234' is now highlighted. now I click between c and 1 I am supposed to get 'abc'. But I'm getting 'abc1234' which is previous highlighted text. If I click again between c and 1 I will get 'abc'. My question is, is there any way that I can get 'abc' on first click (between c and 1)?

Comment: I can't reproduce on macOS (FF & Chrome), the behavior is the expected one here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this example:

```
import $ from "jQuery";
$(document).on('selectionchange', function(){
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  console.log(sel.toString(),sel.type);
});
```

or

```
import $ from "jQuery";
$(document).on("selectionchange", function () {
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  if ($(sel.anchorNode).closest(".test-subject").length > 0) {
    console.log(sel.toString(), sel.type);
  }
});
```

if you need to track only selection in `.test-subject` element

Comment: IMO you will never get 'abc' as the selection if you click between 'c' and '1' (even if you use the shift key). As you can change the selection by dragging the cursor over the text, the 'click' handler is not the best way to handle selection (in the given case, selection change won't be detected)

Comment: I'm getting the same output as 'click' event. Suppose, no text is selected right now. I click between 'a' and 'b'. then, the focus offset will be 1. Now, select 'abc' and the focus offset will be 3. 'abc' is highlighted now. if I click between 'a' and 'b' now focus offset will be '0'. though, it should be '1'. If I click again on the same position then api returns the correct/expected value which is '1'. I have to click two times to make this work. But I want this happened from first click/selectionchange event.

Comment: If you click on the existing selection, getSelection() will return type = "None". For the next click, you will get type = "Caret". Not sure that you can change this behavior. Maybe to try to retrigger the same click event on the same event (tried, but it didn't work in my test code).